# Calculating derivative of a vector function

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the following functions $$f:\mathbb R^2 \to\mathbb R^2,\;(x,y)\mapsto (e^x+\sin(xy),x+y^2x)\\g(x,y):=f \circ f\circ f$$

Calculate $dg(0,0)$.

At the first sight I need at first determine a general Jacobi-Matrix (that means for the double composition of $\;f$) and only after that I can calculate $dg(0,0)$ by inserting zeros in the final expression. This is a problem from a calculus book, where there is also a solution for it, having looked on which, I was a bit surprised by it. Here's how the author of the book solves this problem:
$$
f(0,0)=(1,0),\; f(f(0,0))=f(1,0)=(e,1)\\
df=\left( \begin{matrix}e^x+y\cos (xy) & x\cos(xy)\\ 1+y^2&2xy \end{matrix} \right)\\
dg(0,0)=df(f(f(0,0)))\cdot df(f(0,0)) \cdot df(0,0)=df(e,1)\cdot df(1,0) \cdot df(0,0) = \dots
$$

No need to go further, because this is the point, that confuses me. Instead of first determining general matrix for the function $g$ he inserts $(0,0)$ right away and then determines the derivative with already inserted values instead of general $(x,y)$. The question is if it is legal to do like that. I was thinking, that, in order to find which value takes a derivative of some function takes at the certain point, you need at first to find the general derivative (!) and only after that you can insert the certain values and not vice versa, insert the values and derive the function with values inserted.

Where do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

The author is simply making use of the chain rule. [Read about it here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions).

Comment: I know what a chain rule is, specifically because this is an illustration to how to use the chain rule :) My question is not about using the chain rule, but about the fact, that he formally at firsts evaluates function at the certain point and only after that takes the derivative of it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your confusion is. I suggest reviewing exactly what the chain rule says. The author follows it exactly here. In particular, there is no need to determine the matrix $dg(x, y)$

Comment: I thought the last line in the solution I wrote should have been $$dg(x,y)=df(f(f(x,y)))\cdot df(f(x,y)) \cdot df(x,y)= \dots$$
That's the chain rule, isn't it? But he inserts $(0,0)$ right away. After finding all 3 Jacobi-Matrices we can insert value in them.

Comment: There is! I ask if it is legal so substitute $(x,y)$ with $(0,0)$ before finding matrices for $(x,y)$

Comment: @DmitryKazakov There's only one Jacobi matrix to find; namely $df$. Once you have it, you plug in the values $(0,0)$, $f(0, 0)$ and $f(f(0, 0))$. This gives you three matrices which you multiply together to get $dg(0, 0)$

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks